# Windows free program for batch watermarking files

Tags: windows, gratis, image-processing, photography, digital-watermarking

I'm publishing albums of photos on my blog and Facebook and I'd like to add watermarks to them.

I've found tutorials for programs such as Gimp, but they require long manually applying procedure for each file.

Is there a free program for Windows that would add a watermark to many files at the same time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/).

It has extensive batch options (File > Batch Conversion). I've used IrfanView a lot in the past for batch resizing of images, for which it seemed pretty efficient and easy to use. You can select a few simple operations from a list for the batch/conversion process. Adding watermark-texts is one of them.

[This tutorial](http://fullersfolio.weebly.com/1/post/2012/01/batch-watermarking-images-in-irfanview.html) explains how to overlay a text watermark to these files.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [**Daminion**](http://daminion.net) (I work at Daminion Software). This is a photo management software that you can use to watermark your images. Daminion Free version allows you to work with 15,000 images that can be imported per one local catalog.

**How it works:**

1. Import your photos to Daminion.
2. Select images that you want to stamp by your watermark.
3. Configure an export preset. Your images might be converted and optimized along with adding a watermark.

   [image]
4. Add a watermark to selected Export preset in PNG format (4).

   [image]
5. You can preview how your watermark will be applied to your images before starting the Watermarking process.

   [image]

In addition to visual watermarks, Daminion can also write your Copyrights and Rights Usage Terms into image (in the IPTC and XMP metadata).

Answer (score 4):

[Xnconvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/#downloads) is small, portable and fast for those tasks

> XnConvert is a powerful and free cross-platform batch image processor, allowing you to combine over 80 actions. Compatible with 500 formats.

1. When you open XNconvert, drag&drop all your pictures into *Input*
2. Under actions, select `Add action » Image » Watermark`
3. Choose your watermark file, opacity, size and position
4. Set a path and file type under output for your processed images

   [[image]

   <sup>screenshot where a watermark is applied to hundreds of pictures</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K64zr.png)

For even quicker processing, you could save your settings at the bottom left into a script and reload it every time.

Comment: "If you intend to use XnConvert in a company, you must purchase a license."

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/) gives you a command line, (or batch file), able to do exactly this sort of operation.  [This section](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#wmark_text) of the documentation gives some of the many options to watermark images with either text, images or images generated from text.
[image]

Answer (score -3):

If you use this software regularly you will do yourself a favor and pay (a small amount) for an easier to use and overall better solution than to get a free program that makes you lose time and is not enjoyable to use.

As you know nothing is free and if you choose a "free" program it will also come bundled with some "niceties" be it adware/spyware, bugs or a Windows 95 like interface. Because we (the developers) also have to make a living out of our work.

So here are my paid solutions (with free trials) for watermarking images in batch mode for Win/Mac and iPhone/iPad:

- [photomarksapp.com](http://www.photomarksapp.com/)
- [batchphoto.com/howto/watermark.html](http://www.batchphoto.com/howto/watermark.html)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not all free, and especially FOSS, software comes with adds, spyware, bugs, etc., and often it has a nicer UI than some of the paid solutions which may also have bugs, adds, spyware, etc.